# C# Splitting a list based on items

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a list with following items (lets call it 'main list'):

```
[1,2,2,3,1,2,3,4,4,1,2,2]
```

My goal is to split it into smaller lists that will contain '1' and the following numbers (until the next '1' occurs).
The end result should look like this:

```
[1,2,2,3]
[1,2,3,4,4]
[1,2,2]
```

Some additional info:

1. small lists can be of different lengths
2. the main list always starts with '1' (so you don't have to look for the beginning)
3. the elements of the main list and smaller lists are strings!
4. the number of smaller lists depends on the number of '1' in the main list

Basically I need to split a list of strings to smaller lists of strings.

The first idea that came to my mind was to create a ('final') list containing smaller lists, so I created a loop:

```
List<string> templist = new List<string>();
List<List<string> final = new List<List<string>();

foreach (string log in mainlist)
{
 if (log != '1')
    {
    templist.Add(log);
    }
 else
    {
     final.add(templist);
     templist.Clear();
     templist.Add(log)}
    }
final.add(templog);
```

it seems to work but I get a list with duplicates:
[[1,2,2],[1,2,2],[1,2,2]]

Comment: obvious solution ... not clear ... create new

Answer (score 2):

you can do this.

check for 1 and initialize the current list with default item 1 (add the current list to the final list in this step as well)

and if not one then keep on adding the items to the current list.

```
List<string> currentList = null;
List<string> mainList = new List<string> { "1", "2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "1", "2", "2" };
List<List<string>> finalList = new List<List<string>>();

            
foreach (string item in mainList)
{
    if (item == "1")
    {
        currentList = new List<string>() { item };
        finalList.Add(currentList);
    }
    else
    {
        currentList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: simple and works - just what I was looking for! One more thing: what if I want the function to return these smaller lists (separately) OR save them to the given path in separate files?

Comment: @KotAngens just change the return type to List<List<string>>. You can convert this to json and write to the file

Answer (score 0):

Can be:

```
 else
 {
     templist = new List<string>(){log};
     final.add(templist);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of all occurrences of `1`. Then according to these indexes and using the two functions [Take()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-7.0) and [Skip()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-7.0) to separate the lists..

```
List<string> mainlist = new List<string>{"1","2","2","3","1","2","3","4","4","1","2","2"};
List<List<string>> final = new List<List<string>>();

var numberOfList = mainlist.Select((item, index) => new {val = item,ind = index})
                                    .Where(item => item.val == "1").ToList();


for(int i = 0; i<numberOfList.Count;i++)
{
    if(i == numberOfList.Count-1)
        final.Add(mainlist.Skip(numberOfList[i].ind)
                          .Take(mainlist.Count - numberOfList[i].ind).ToList());
    else
        final.Add(mainlist.Skip(numberOfList[i].ind)
                          .Take(numberOfList[i + 1].ind - numberOfList[i].ind).ToList());
}
```

result:

> [1,2,2,3]

> [1,2,3,4,4]

> [1,2,2]

Comment: I guess it's because your code is rather inefficient. The main list is iterated multiple times even though the problem can be solved in one iteration. I also try to always format the code such that readers wont have to scroll vertically, which I find very annoying.